# Javascript: using regex to split and store?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

So I am doing a practice exam in preparation for my Javascript/HTML, and one of the questions is these:
[image: Practice exam question]

What I came up with was:

```
function check(date_str){
  var split1 = date_str.split(" ");
  var split2 = date_str.split(":");
  var split3 = split1[3].slice(0,2);
  var obj = [
  {"month": split1[0]},
  {"date": split1[1]},
  {"year": split1[2]},
  {"hour": split3},
  {"minute": split2[1]},
  {"second": split2[2]}
  ];
  return obj;
```

which obviously doesn't use regex, as the question asks us too. I tried doing this:

(\w+)(\d+)(\d+)(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)

which I don't know if it's right or not.

Another question I have is I'm unsure on how to store the strings split from the regex expressions into the JSON object? Are they stored in an array after splitting? Do they have an index?

Please give me any pointers and point me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is a great opportunity to make great use of capture groups.

Because your input string is rigidly formatted, you can use it to make your regular expression. Let's start with that. Take the input string and then break it down into what should be there:

1. Start with the string format: `/CCC dd yyyy hh:mm:ss/`
2. `d`, `y`, `h`, `m`, and `s`, are all precisely one digit: `/CCC \d\d \d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/`
3. Simplify with exact quantifiers: `/CCC \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/`
4. CCC can only be `jan`, `feb`, or `mar`, so we can replace that with a non-capturing group with three options:`/(?:jan|feb|mar) \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/`
5. The the month field should be case-insensitive, and the rest are numbers and whitespace, so we can safely use the case-insensitive flag, `i`, instead of handling the options directly: `/(?:jan|feb|mar) \d{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/i`
6. Finally, the instructions say that there can be more than one space between the elements, so add we have to add the appropriate quantifier after each space: `/(?:jan|feb|mar) +\d{2} +\d{4} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/i`

You now have a regular expression that matches your input requirements precisely:
`/(?:jan|feb|mar) +\d{2} +\d{4} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/i`

However, that doesn't get you the data out that you need. For that, you need to use capture groups. For each field that you need, put a capture group around the characters that will match it. (Or, in the case of the month, just remove `?:` to convert the non-capture group to a capture group.)
`/(jan|feb|mar) +(\d{2}) +(\d{4}) +(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/i`

This gives you six capture groups, one for each field that you need. From there, it's just a matter of populating the fields of a new object.

Here's the complete code:

```
// Here's the function.
function check(date_string){
    // Make the pattern and use it to match the date_string.
    var date_pattern = /(jan|feb|mar) +(\d{2}) +(\d{4}) +(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/i;
    var match = date_string.match(date_pattern);

    // If it wasn't a match, return null.
    if (!match) return null;

    // Otherwise, return a new object from the capture groups.
    return {
        month: match[1],
        date: match[2],
        year: match[3],
        hour: match[4],
        minute: match[5],
        second: match[6]
    };
}

// This bit is test code.
var input_string = "Jan 10 2016 10:11:12";
var result = check(input_string);
if (result) console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
else console.log("Result was null");
```

Hopefully, this helps. Regex is a wonderful, powerful tool once you learn it fully.

**Edit: As another commenter said, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) is an amazing tool to help test and debug your regular expressions. I use it daily in my professional life. There's another useful tool called [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/javascript) that is nice to writing and executing arbitrary Javascript code (as well as some other languages). That's what I used to test the code I provided.

Comment: Wow this is so good! I would never have thought of doing this way, guess that's just how computer science is! Thank you very much!